# how to get multiple input at the same time in javascript?

Tags: javascript, user-input

Is there a better way to display and get multiple inputs at the same time rather than it popping up twice on the client screen using javascript ?

```
   var r = prompt("enter username");
   var r = prompt("enter emailID");
```

Comment: don't pop up at all (use a form) or use a form in a modal if you think it deserves to behave like a dialog

Comment: When working on the client-side I'd recommend using a form.

Comment: Most programmers are used to getting input like this from command line programming. Don't do this in a visual environment. Use a `form`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var r = prompt("Enter username, password"),
    v = r.split(","),
    username,
    password;

if(c.length === 2) {
    username = v[0].trim();
    password = v[1].trim();
}
```

But still you can better use a form.